# Make list of columns numeric - R

Tags: r

As always, apologies for the simple Q.

I've got a large dataset and want to change a specified list of columns into a numeric class. I can do it, but it's not very elegant and unless I change the memory requirements it won't run as the merge is too exhausts the vector memory!

```
library(tidyverse)

#Extract column names I want to turn into numeric from data
make_numeric <- data[252:321] %>% select(-c(contains("UNITS"))) %>% colnames()
```

Here I want to turn columns that are contained in `make_numeric` into `as.numeric` and insert straight back into `data`. I can't do this in one go, so instead I extract the data, convert, and then merge.

```
tmp <- data %>% select(record_id, make_numeric)
tmp <- lapply(tmp[2:56], as.numeric)
tmp <- as.data.frame(tmp)
tmp2 <- data %>% select(-make_numeric)
tmp3 <- merge(tmp, tmp2)
```

I'm certain there must be a better way...

Comment: Why are they not imported as numeric to begin with? Or is that not an option?

Comment: Not an option....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a dplyr solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)

#Extract column names I want to turn into numeric from data
make_numeric <- data[252:321] %>% select(-c(contains("UNITS"))) %>% colnames()

#Mutate desired columns to numeric
data <- data %>% mutate_at(vars(make_numeric), as.numeric)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
library(data.table)

#convert to data.table
dt<- as.data.table(data)

#change colnames to numeric
dt[, colnames(dt)[colnames(dt) %in% cols] := lapply(.SD, as.numeric), .SDcols = colnames(dt)[colnames(dt) %in% cols]]
```

Comment: Sadly not... 

`Error in `[.data.table`(dt, , `:=`(make_numeric, lapply(.SD, as.numeric)),  : 
  Supplied 56 items to be assigned to 6310 items of column 'make_numeric'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to make this intent clear to readers of your code.`

Comment: What about now?